# not getting createStoredProcedureQuery method using session object

Tags: hibernate

```
session.createStoredProcedureQuery("procedureName");
```

I am only getting `session.createSQLQuery`

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>         
    </dependency>
```

I want to use it for executing a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) for the Session object, you'll notice that the method that you're looking for is not there. If you need to run a store procedure with Hibernate, you can use one of the methods described [here](http://www.baeldung.com/stored-procedures-with-hibernate-tutorial).

Comment: In the methods told by you.i m using the one with createStoredProcedureQuery

Comment: for this i require session.createStoredProcedureQuery

Comment: Please use session.getNamedQuery

Answer (score 0):

The method `session.createStoredProcedureQuery("procedureName");` is not available in hibernate.Hibernate allows to express queries in native SQL format directly. Therefore, we can straightforwardly create a native SQL query, and use the CALL statement to call the stored procedure like following:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL yourStoreProcedure()").addEntity(SomeEntity.class);
List<SomeEntity> allData = query.list();
```

Where addEntity() method to get entity objects from the native SQL query.